# ngTable is not showing properly in chrome? in Firefox and IE 9 its working fine?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, ngtable

> Below is the table which i am rendering which is working fine in IE
>   and 
>       Firefox. But not working as expected in chrome.
>       12th header(certificate of Incorporation or equivaleent) is coming at first and second header(RequestType) is coming at 12th place and 1st header(Request#) is coming at 2nd place
>       place. 
>       When i removed all the  and trying to show one by one. It was working
>       fine till (data-title="'Bank'"). and when i just added another  
>       (data-title="'Borad'"). Header is coming improperly.

[image: improper header]

```html
<table ng-show="reqTrackCtrl.data.length" ng-table="reqTrackCtrl.reqTrackingTable">
  <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in reqTrackCtrl.data">
    <td data-title="'Request#'" sortable="'id'" class="item-id"><a href="#">{{item.id}}</a></td>
    <td data-title="'Request Type'" sortable="'class'"><a href="#">{{item.class}}</a></td>
    <td data-title="'Status'" sortable="'requestStatus'">{{item.request}}
    <td data-title="'Requester'" sortable="'requestedBy'">{{item.requestedBy}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Requested Date'" sortable="'requestedDate'">{{item.requestedDate}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Assigned To'" sortable="'assignedTo'">{{item.assignedTo}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Completion Date'" sortable="'completionDate'">{{item.completionDate}}</td>
    <td ng-if="formType != 'DU'" data-title="'Business Unit'" sortable="'Unit'">{{item.Unit}}</td>
    <td ng-if="formType != 'DU'" data-title="'Legal Entity Name'" sortable="'EntityName'">{{item.EntityName}}</td>
    <td ng-if="formType != 'DU'" data-title="'Bank'">{{item.bank}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Board'">{{item.boardResolution}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Certificate of Incorporation or Equivalent'">{{item.certificate Of incorporation}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Bylaws'"><div >{{item.bylaws}}</div></td>
    <td data-title="'Incumbency'">{{item.incumbency}}</td>
    <td ng-show="formType != 'ABC'" data-title="'Delegation'">{{item.delegation}}</td>
    <td ng-show="formType != 'ABC'" data-title="'FAT'">{{item.FAT}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Bank Forms'">{{item.bankForms}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Signature'">{{item.signature}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Bank System'">{{item.bankSystem}}</td></td>
    <td data-title="'Kyriba'">{{item.kyriba}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Account'">{{item.account}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Shared'">{{item.shared}}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For resolving this issue I have updated ng-table version, from 0.5.4 to 1.0.0.